# Update Secondary Tile On Click

Tags: windows-phone-8, live-tile

How can I update my secondary tile without navigating to a page? I wish to use secondary tiles to ie. set WiFi/Bluetooth on/off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tapping on a tile will trigger a navigation to the associated URI, there's nothing you can do about that. The best you can do is exiting the application as soon as the page is loaded.

Comment: Sadly this seems to be the only way to go.